# Indecomposable integral representations of a group of order 2 "by hand"

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

This question is a duplicate of
[that 2010 MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27129/involutions-in-gl-nz/27145#27145).

I am interested in classifying isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional integral representations of the cyclic group $C_2$ of order $2$.
Clearly, any integral  representation of $C_2$ is a direct sum of *indecomposable* integral representations.

The following result is well-known:

> **Theorem.**
> The group $C_2$ has exactly 3 isomorphism classes of indecomposable integral representations:
>
> (1) trivial;
>
> (2) the  sign representation;
>
> (3) the 2-dimensional representation with matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right).$

This result was stated in [the answer  of Victor Protsak](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27145/4149).
See also [the answer of Todd Leason](https://mathoverflow.net/a/204589/4149).

In [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27129/involutions-in-gl-nz/27145#comment57961_27145)
Victor Protsak gives a reference. He writes: "Curtis and Reiner, Chapter 11.
It's a special case of a theorem in Section 74 which classifies integral representations of cyclic groups of prime order.
Naturally, this case is much easier and can be done by hand."

> **Question.** How to prove the above theorem "by hand", without reference to the book by Curtis and Reiner?

**Motivation:** I am working now with algebraic $\mathbb R$-tori.
They are classified by integral representations of the Galois group
${\rm Gal}({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb R})$, which is a group of order $2$.
In order to understand the well-known classification of indecomposable $\mathbb R$-tori,
I need to understand the well-known classification
of indecomposable  integral representations of ${\rm Gal}({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb R})$.

I asked this seemingly elementary question on [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3789999/37763),
but got no answers or comments, so I ask it here.

Comment: Casselman has a nice write-up of this classification of indecomposable tori … somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Ah, here we go.  Theorem 2, p. 3, of [Casselman - Computing with real tori](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/realtori.pdf).  Let me know if this reference suffices as an answer; I leave it as a comment for now in case you're hoping for a more MO-answer-sized proof.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Let us wait...

Comment: @LSpice: If you post this reference to Bill Casselman as an answer, I will be happy to accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Computing with real tori](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/realtori.pdf), Casselman has a nice write-up of this theorem from the point of view of not just proving that these are the only indecomposable tori, but, supposing you are given an explicit integral representation of $\operatorname C_2$, explicitly finding/computing its decomposition into these three representations.

In fact, if you (you the general reader, not necessarily @MikhailBorovoi) aren't familiar with Bill Casselman's recent work, it's well worth checking out his page [http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass); he's been very interested for a while in doing actual computations, in the sense of things that can be fed into a computer, relating to algebraic groups.  The above is one example; others can be found at [http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/publications.html](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/publications.html), including, for example, [The computation of structure constants according to Jacques Tits](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/Tits.pdf)—things that we all know *can* be done but that most of us (at least I!) would shrink from actually *doing*, here laid out in a way that demonstrates how to carry it out practically.

(There's also some nice stuff on [mathematical graphics](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/graphics/)!)

Comment: The first link in your answer does not open.

Comment: Huh, [sorry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369239/indecomposable-integral-representations-of-a-group-of-order-2-by-hand/369306#comment932328_369306); it opens for me.  The target is https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/realtori.pdf .  If you can figure out what needs to be done to make it open for you, then please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

See Appendix A in [M. Borovoi and D. A. Timashev, Galois cohomology and component group of a real reductive group](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.13062).